# Delay For Ad Popup Onclick

Tags: javascript, popup

I have done many tests using `defer attribute`, `asynch attribute`, `settimeout function`. Here 1 tested method from an user of Stack:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'http://example.com/some/script.js';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}, 2000);
</script>
```

But without success.

My goal is theorically simple: I have 2 popup code that starting if an user click on Alertbox. I need for apply a delay on 1 popup, this the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx.xxxx.net/pop.js"></script>
```

Some ideas that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what your asking but maybe setTimeout is what you need.

i.e

```
setTimeout( yourPopupFunction(), <delay in ms>);
```

Comment: I have testing setTimeout but not works. I tried also with defer and asynch attribute but nothing.

Comment: I have added a method used for testing the delay.

Comment: If the popup is running as soon as the .js file loads appending to the body not the head should work for you

Comment: document.body.appendChild instead of document.head.appendChild ?

Comment: yeah ( or document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild )

Comment: Thanks for your help. :)